# How to navigate using nav-item after submit btn click in bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-4

In this Html, I have used nav-item and links. If I click update1 button, it should navigate to tabs-2 nav-link. I tried, but the page is navigating, the nav-link is not getting active.Can you please help me out?

Html:

```
         <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#tabs-1" role="tab">Video consultation</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tabs-2" role="tab">In-clinic consultation</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tabs-3" role="tab">Time Off</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content mb-5">
          <div class="tab-pane active" id="tabs-1" role="tabpanel">
            <div class="carddesign" style="padding: 20px;">
                 <div>form1</div>
                 <button>update1<button>
            </div>
          </div>
           <div class="tab-pane" id="tabs-2" role="tabpanel">
            <div class="row carddesign" style="padding:0px 15px 40px;">
               <div>form2</div>
               <button>update2<button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have navigation issues because of `class="nav-link active"` that's not dynamic so your display div will be always nav number one.
To fix that you have to do some change.
I suppose you are developing an angular app so first in your **.ts** file you need to add two things :

1. add a variable named   for example `selectedTab` and we pass an initial value of 1.
2. add this function  :

```
 public onClickSelectTab(navIndex: number) {
    return (this.selectedTab = navIndex);
  }
```

to resume your .ts have to look like this:

```
 selectedTab = 1;

  public onClickSelectTab(navIndex: number) {
    return (this.selectedTab = navIndex);
  }
```

After that update you have to do some changes in your **.html** file

3. add a `(click)` param to your a tags like this:

```
  <li class="nav-item">
      <a
        class="nav-link active"
        (click)="onClickSelectTab(1)"
        data-toggle="tab"
        href="./#tabs-1"
        role="tab"
        >Video consultation</a
      >
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a
        class="nav-link"
        data-toggle="tab"
        (click)="onClickSelectTab(2)"
        href="./#tabs-2"
        role="tab"
        >In-clinic consultation</a
      >
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a
        class="nav-link"
        (click)="onClickSelectTab(3)"
        data-toggle="tab"
        href="./#tabs-3"
        role="tab"
        >Time Off</a
      >
    </li>
```

2. add dynamic class to your div :

```
  <div
      class="tab-pane"
      [ngClass]="{'active':selectedTab===1 } "
      id="tabs-1"
      role="tabpanel"
    >
      <div class="carddesign" style="padding: 20px;">
        <div>form1</div>
        <button>update1</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div
      class="tab-pane"
      [ngClass]="{'active':selectedTab===2 } "
      id="tabs-2"
      role="tabpanel"
    >
      <div class="row carddesign" style="padding: 0px 15px 40px;">
        <div>form2</div>
        <button>update2</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div
      [ngClass]="{'active':selectedTab===3 } "
      class="tab-pane"
      id="tabs-3"
      role="tabpanel"
    >
      <div class="carddesign" style="padding: 20px;">
        <div>form3</div>
        <button>update3</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

see an example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-bootstrap4-start-template-forked-slltw?file=/src/app/app.component.html:744-1546).

Comment: This solution is still not working properly,

Answer (score 0):

You better replace `<button>update1<button>` on `<a href="#tabs-2">update1</a>`

If you using angular use `<a [routerLink]="['/tabs-2']">update1</a>`

Or do it in code

```js
<button (click)="navigateToTabs2()">update1<button>

constructor(private router: Router) { }

navigateToTabs2() {
  this.router.navigate(['/tabs-2']);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. this will not help, since it is nav-link, not routerLink.

Comment: <a data-toggle="tab" href="#tabs-3" role="tab"> <button>update1<button></a>

Comment: My solution looks like this, its changing the tabs content, but current tab is not getting active.

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
       <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" [ngClass]="{'active':selectedTab===1 }" data-toggle="tab" href="#tabs-1" role="tab">Video consultation</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link"  [ngClass]="{'active':selectedTab===2 }" data-toggle="tab" href="#tabs-2" role="tab">In-clinic consultation</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link"  [ngClass]="{'active':selectedTab===3 }" data-toggle="tab" href="#tabs-3" role="tab">Time Off</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
     <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12" style="margin-left: 70%;" 
       (click)="updateSevenProfile()">
          <a (click)="onClickSelectTab(3)" data-toggle="tab" href="#tabs-3" 
               role="tab">
             <button>Update1</button>
          </a>
        </div>
```